# Calling Javascript function from Java using JSObject

Tags: java, javascript, javascript-framework

I'm just trying to call a Javascript function from Java using JSObject. I need the Javascript function to update an HTML text field. For this I need to know the element ID and the value.

I have tried this but it doesn't work.  When trying to access from Javascript the values passed are empty.

So my question is how can I access those values from Javascript?  I must be missing something.

If I declare objects of size 1 it will work, but I need to pass 2 values in objects array.

Thanks in advance.

```
//Java code
Object[] objects = new Object[2];
objects[0] = "elementId";
objects[1] = "elementValue";
window.call("updateElement",objects);

//Javascript code
function updateElement(array){
  alert(array[0]);
  alert(array[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I noticed that you are using an Object array in java and passing in string values.
Have you tried using a String array?

```
String[] x = new String[2];
x[0] = "elementId";
x[1] = "elementValue";
window.call("updateElement", x);
```

give that a try and see if that works. my guess is that javascript isnt able to realize that object array being passed is a string array. though i am not 100% sure.

Comment: If I do this in my Javascript it works:

 var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);  

I guess I need to parse the arguments in a special way. And the function doesn't take any arguments!

Answer (score 1):

In your example you should see `alert('e')` and `alert('l')` show up because you're passing two arguments to 'updateElement'. You can always use the `arguments` object in javascript to inspect what you really received.

I suggest to always create the final argument list separately and last, so you don't have this problem. It's just a horrible design flaw that they didn't update the signature to `JSObject.call(String, Object...)` in Java 5, we would have much less headaches that way.

A cleaner solution would be:

```
// Java code
window.call("updateElement", new Object[] { "elementId", "elementValue" });

// Javascript code
function updateElement(elId, elVal){
    alert(elId);
    alert(elVal);
}
```

but if you really want to stick to receiving an array in JS:

```
String[] arr = new String[] { "elementId", "elementValue" };
window.call("updateElement", new Object[] { arr });
```

Answer (score 0):

The way call works is that you pass in *an array of the functions arguments*. Here you have only **one** argument ( your array), so you need to call it like :

```
//Java code
Object[][] objects = new Object[][1];
objects[0]=new Object[2];
objects[0][0] = "elementId";
objects[0][1] = "elementValue";
window.call("updateElement",objects);
```